# Why can't I select all polygons in my DXF layer?

Tags: qgis, polygon, dxf

I am importing dxf file into QGIS. The file contains polygons. For some reason, when I select them only some of them are selected. Why can't I select all off them.

Here is how it looks like: (yellow is the selected polygons)
[image]

Comment: Did you check if the number of selected features matches the visualization? If not it could be that, that some features are doubles, meaning two features have the same shape and position and therefore just one is selected

Answer (score 3):

Most likely these polygons are corrupted. That happens often with CAD imports when CAD workers aren't meticulously drawing their closed polylines (which then are converted to polygons).

Use the Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Check Validity tool or select the polygon using the node editor and let it validate the polygon to see what issues exist, then fix it manually. If you have many such issues, look into mass-fixing methods such as v.clean offered by the GRASS toolkit (cleaning tool bpol seems to work fairly well).

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't seem to have errors. I run the check Validity tool and it creates the same shapes on top of the old ones.

Comment: use the topology checker plugin http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html

Answer (score 0):

May be file is corrupted or not. 
Some times its happens due to overlapping If Polygons are overlapped. Open Attribute Table and Select the polygon you wanted. Sometimes its happens due to multiple shape files.